# Docker MySQL connection refused on different port

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

So I am running a few Docker containers on a host that has MySQL already running on it. I would like to also run MySQL in a Docker container on that same machine. I set up my Docker compose file to use 3307 instead but when my application tries to get a DB connection I see:

```
web_1     | Could not connect ... 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db:3307' (111 Connection refused)
web_1     | 10.0.2.2 - - [04/Mar/2019 21:06:31] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I have tried all sorts of different network configurations but each one creates a new issue. Here is the compose file I am 
[docker-compose.yml file](https://gist.github.com/jimmygoogle/f2b313893a0972d0c3bf71aa7dd06d1f) using and the output of 'docker container ps'

```
[jim@localhost ~]$ docker container ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED            STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
a0f12368ee8d        jimpython_web       "python ./app.py"        4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp              jimpython_web_1
9b0efbf08069        jimpython_celery    "celery worker -A ..."   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                                            jimpython_celery_1
fcc72e5a9fdd        mysql:5.7           "docker-entrypoint..."   15 minutes ago      Up 4 minutes        33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp   jimpython_db_1
0b65a78a56f2        redis:alpine        "docker-entrypoint..."   15 minutes ago      Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp              jimpython_redis_1
3c2d1551c165        mongo               "docker-entrypoint..."   15 minutes ago      Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp            jimpython_mongo_1
```

I was hoping to not change the port that MySQL in Docker is running on if possible. Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're connecting to the database from another Docker container. When you do so, the exposed/forwarded port isn't used, so you should still use 3306 from there. You'll only use 3307 when connecting to it from outside of Docker.

Comment: When I do that I get 'address already in use' when I start everything up.

Comment: @Jim What are you changing exactly when you do it that way? I think you're changing it in too many places.

Comment: I change the docker-compose file from '3307:3306' to '3306:3306'

Comment: @Jim Yep, that's somewhere you shouldn't be changing it. Leave that at 3307:3306, and just change `web` to try to connect to it on 3306.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I am confused as to why. Isnt mysql listening on 3307 for the db container? I am learning Docker and the networking stuff is throwing me for a loop.

Comment: @Jim The ports in the docker-compose file only affect connections outside the containers. Connections inside them don't go through that, so they're always on the original port.

Answer (score 1):

This post:
https://dev.to/pmutua/run-mysql-on-port-3307-using-docker-compose-gf8 Define port on mysql configuration file:

```
 mysqldb:
  image: mysql
  ports:
  - 3307:3307
  environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
  - MYSQL_TCP_PORT=3307
  volumes:
  - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  - mysql_config:/etc/mysql
```