# Can't dockerize a web app: java.net.ConnectException

Tags: java, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a web app that uses MySQL. I was hoping to "dockerize" it so that I learn to use Docker and at the same time make my app more "shareable" (anyone could check it out without downloading and setting up a MySQL server). Here's my attempt:

#### Step 1. Write `Dockerfile`

In the project root I created a file called Dockerfile with the following content:

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk

WORKDIR /app

COPY target/spring_bootstrap-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java", "-jar", "spring_bootstrap-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

#### Step 2. Write `docker-compose.yml`

I need to have both JDK and a MySQL server components in my container. As I understand, I need a `docker-compose.yml` file. Here's what it looks like:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3307/users_db?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: pp_user
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: pp_user

  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: users_db
      MYSQL_USER: pp_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pp_user
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
```

You might be wondering why it's 3307. It's because for some reason 3306 was already occupied (I have no idea why, MySQL server doesn't seem to be running outside the Docker container)

#### Step 3. Remove datasource properties from `application.properties`

```
# connection properties
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users_db?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
#spring.datasource.username=pp_user
#spring.datasource.password=pp_user
```

#### Step 4. Clean and package so that I have an up-to-date jar

#### Step 5. Navigate to the project directory and run `docker-compose up`

The command produced colossal log output. My MySQL server got up and running, but the project itself failed

[image: the Docker Desktop screenshot showing that MySQL is running, the app has "exited"]

This was the killer. Not very informative to me, though

```
bootstrap_fetch-app-1  | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
bootstrap_fetch-app-1  |        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
bootstrap_fetch-app-1  |        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
bootstrap_fetch-app-1  |        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:547) ~[na:na]
bootstrap_fetch-app-1  |        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:602) ~[na:na]
bootstrap_fetch-app-1  |        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
bootstrap_fetch-app-1  |        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
bootstrap_fetch-app-1  |        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
bootstrap_fetch-app-1  |        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
bootstrap_fetch-app-1  |        ... 51 common frames omitted
bootstrap_fetch-app-1  |
bootstrap_fetch-app-1 exited with code 1
```

What may be the problem? Please let me know if you need more details

Comment: In case it's relevant, Windows Task Manager shows two `mysqld` processes (maybe it has something to do with 3306 being occupied). No other MySQL-related processes were discovered

Comment: Maybe, I need to add and run some additional image (Tomcat, for example)?

Comment: You're declaring env variables like SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL but you're not using them anywhere. Uncomment your application.properties file and configure the properties like spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL} and see if it works.

Comment: Alternatively, you can check the answer in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66169935/how-to-set-spring-datasource-url-inside-a-docker-container

Comment: Connections between containers don't use (or require) `ports:`.  In the Compose file setting `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL`, does changing the port number back to the standard MySQL port 3306 help?  (Spring knows how to set the `spring.datasource.url` property from that environment variable, you don't need to change your jar file at all.)  Also see _e.g._ [Docker MySQL connection refused on different port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54993731/docker-mysql-connection-refused-on-different-port).

Comment: @CaptainAye thank you, you helped me a lot. See the answer

Comment: @DavidMaze thank you, you helped me a lot. See the answer

Comment: It seems to work, but I'm not 100% certain. I now can't just open Workbench and make sure the changes in the UI are actually reflected in the database with a simple `SELECT` query. Can I somehow access that database data from outside the Docker container? I can't just type `localhost:3307` in my browser and get some web interface to perform my queries (in fact, I don't get any meaningful response at all when I do that)

Comment: Once I open MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client, I'm simply prompted to enter a password, presumably from my root user. At this point, I can't execute any commands relating to my Docker db. Once I enter the password, I'm automatically connected to my local MySQL server and the only thing I can do is to execute queries. Can MySQL Command Line Client even help me in achieving my goal (to connect to the Docker db and execute a query to check my web app updates database data, not just the UI)? `mysql` doesn't work in a regular Powershell

Comment: Oh, I figured that out. See the answer's edit

Comment: What kinda annoys me a bit, though, is that 3307:3306 mismatch. Is that the right way to do it after all? 3306:3306 doesn't work, but maybe I was supposed to resolve that some other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem had to do with these mistakes

##### 1. Not including the properties

I had to reference the `docker-compose.yml` properties in my `application.properties` file

```
spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
```

##### 2. Specifying a wrong port

Even though the host port was 3307, I still needed to specify 3306 in my property

```yaml
# the correct version

version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      # note the change in the following line
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/users_db?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: pp_user
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: pp_user

  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: users_db
      MYSQL_USER: pp_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pp_user
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
```

If you want to access the database running inside the Docker container and check that the data is actually modified, you can install MySQL Shell (I used MySQL Installer), run it, and execute something like this

```
MySQL Shell 8.0.34 
Copyright (c) 2016, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates.                                           
Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.                                                                                                                                                                               
Type '\help' or '\?' for help; '\quit' to exit.                                                                           
MySQL  JS > \connect --mysql -h localhost -P 3307 -u pp_user -p                                                        
Creating a Classic session to 'pp_user@localhost:3307'                                                                  
Please provide the password for 'pp_user@localhost:3307': *******                                                       
Save password for 'pp_user@localhost:3307'? [Y]es/[N]o/Ne[v]er (default No): Y                                          
Fetching schema names for auto-completion... Press ^C to stop.                                                          
Your MySQL connection id is 44                                                                                          
Server version: 8.1.0 MySQL Community Server - GPL                                                                      
No default schema selected; type \use <schema> to set one.                                                               
MySQL  localhost:3307 ssl  JS > \sql                                                                                   
Switching to SQL mode... Commands end with ;                                                                            
Fetching global names for auto-completion... Press ^C to stop.                                                          
Error during auto-completion cache update: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation                                                                                                                 
MySQL  localhost:3307 ssl  SQL > select * from users_db.users;
```

I appreciate the help from *CaptainAye* and *David Maze*. They helped me a great deal